# No me muestra Mensaje después de eliminar

Tags: php, mysql, script

Hola tengo un ligero problema intente desde echo hasta print o algun script y nada no sale mensaje despues de eliminar:
para empezar este es mi codigo de mi pagina index.php que pregunta si desea eliminar o no bueno este mensaje si sale:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function eliminar(idc)
 {
    if (confirm("Realmente desea eliminar el registro?"))
    {
      window.location="adservereditarie.php?idc="+idc;
    }
  }
</script>
  </head>
```

el mensaje que no sale es este en mi pagina adservereditarie.php despues de eliminar osea si elimina mis datos hasta ahi bien me redirecciona a la pagina inicial pero no me muestra mensaje bueno me redirecciona por el header no por el windows location:

```
    mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM colegio WHERE idcolegio=$idc");
         echo "<script type=''>
          alert('Los datos del colegio fueron eliminados correctamente');
          window.location='index.php';
        </script>";
   header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: ¿Sabías que antes de `header('location: index.php');` no puede haber absolutamente ninguna salida por pantalla, tales como `echo, print_r, var_dump...` etc?

Comment: hola bueno lo probe despues del header pero nada en mi pagina index no me muestra nada ningun mensaje no habra otra manera porfavor una manito pues..

Comment: ¿Así no funciona?: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Los datos del colegio fueron eliminados correctamente');
        location = 'index.php';
      </script>";` y quitas esto: `header('location: index.php');`?

Comment: Excelente hermano me salvaste el dia gracias amigo te pasaste y gracias por darte un tiempito en leer mi pregunta y tratar de ayudarme gracias....

Comment: Publicaste tu comentario como una *respuesta*. Sugiero que borres esa respuesta que aparece más abajo. Por favor lee: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería funcionar así:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM colegio WHERE idcolegio=$idc");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
        alert('Los datos del colegio fueron eliminados correctamente'); 
        location = 'index.php'; 
      </script>";
```

**Notas:**

1. Esta verificación no será siempre exacta. Deberías invocar a un método como `affected_rows` para verificar que realmente alguna fila fue afectada en la consulta. El código como lo has planteado te dirá que siempre se eliminó el registro y puede que no siempre sea así.
2. Tu consulta es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas con las consultas que usan variables obtenidas desde fuentes externas. No lo ignores, es un problema que atañe seriamente a la seguridad de todo tu sistema.

Comment: Excelente hermano A. Cedano me salvaste el dia gracias amigo te pasaste y gracias por darte un tiempito en leer mi pregunta y tratar de ayudarme gracias.... – deivid7777 hace 9 segundos editar

Comment: disculpa amigo A. Cedano me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor de una consulta preparada y que no sea vulnerable a la inyeccion sql...